# a question about proving limit confused me a lot. Seeing the attached picture.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can anyone teach me how to deal with this kind of question? I am just a first year student in mathematics, and I really find some difficulties on these kind of things. I spent at least 20 hours per week to learn it, but I still cannot solve some problems like this; it disappoint me a lot.
[image]

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to c}^a f(x)=L$ for a given positive number $a$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<a\varepsilon$. Since it is "for every $\varepsilon>0$", you can choose $\varepsilon$ to be $\varepsilon\over a$ and get $\lim_{x\to c}^{} f(x)=L$.

The key point is: $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, so whatever you write it as, $\varepsilon$ or $a\varepsilon$ for a given $a>0$, they are both arbitrary from $0$ to $+\infty$.